# Should ads on Stack Overflow be accessible?

Tags: discussion, advertising, accessibility

I saw the following ad on Stack Overflow (English version, but it is targeted to my language).

[image: Portuguese ad on Stack Overflow about payments on foreign countries]

On the left side is the alt attribute, which roughly translates to:

> You receive money from foreign companies? So stop losing time and
> money, at company name you have: (1) One of the lowest fees on the
> market (2) Transactions made in up to 1 business day (3) Portuguese
> support. COMPANY NAME, WE SPEAK YOUR LANGUAGE. <-- Click on the banner
> to learn more -->

On the right side, the blue text with an arrow on white background, translates to:

> Inspect this banner

Followed by

> if you lose money when transferring money from foreign companies

My translation is not the best, but as you can see the ad makes a "smart" interaction with the user, and uses a long text in its alt attribute with way more information than what would fit in the ad image, and has symbols.

Ad iframes on Stack Overflow have the title of "3rd party ad content", so I believe they are read by screen readers, and I couldn't find any attribute that indicates otherwise. I tested some ad iframes with NVDA and it do notices the alt from the image inside the iframe.

[image: advertisement made by Stack Overflow about the Portuguese version of the website]

The above ad is by Stack Overflow themselves (I suppose), about Stack Overflow in Portuguese, and the alt is just "sb-casa" which translates to "sb-home", that would be good for the name attribute instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines doesn't talk about accessibility, is there any approval in that regard? Or are ads ignored in some other way?

As a note I reported the ad.

Comment: As you see, there is an option for publishers to enter their `alt` text, so it's not accessibility issue, but more ads verification issue. (in my opinion) if ads contents are verified/moderated somehow, this should be applied for `alt` texts too.

Comment: I can't tell for sure but I believe there is some moderation on ads, but it seems like `alt` is completely ignored. I checked Stack Overflow's own banner/ad for collectives and the `alt` is empty, the banner is not just decorative, but if one wants to "hide" their ad from screen readers, then the `iframe` name `3rd party ad content` should be hidden altogether

Comment: In my opinion, ads should be totally *inaccessible* by everyone. But that's just me.

Comment: What's the "big deal"...!?, if you know how to "inspect the Element", => you know how to block it, using any Ad/Script Blocker for your Browser (not mentioned)... All Sites do that, => block and move on...

Comment: I'm very impressed by the techiness of the ad. I do not think we should hinder creativity in ads.

Comment: @chivracq totally miss the point by a wide margin, the question is about accessibility, if it is not a big deal for you or you aren't personally affected, it does not matter

Comment: @trinalbadger587 I also do not think we should hinder creativity in ads, but that's not an excuse to put in almost 300 characters of text in the alt element to promote your company

Comment: @chivracq It is wholly unreasonable to require everyone using screen readers to use web developer tools in the browser just to avoid overly long and/or poorly written alt text in ads.

Comment: Alright, oh I missed the point indeed, well "Accessibility" is a "Concept" that I know and understand, but "accessible", ... well, simply means "accessible" to me, I don't think about "Accessibility" when I see/read "accessible", => so the Qt (Title) (=> "Should ads on Stack Overflow be accessible?") is maybe not very clear..., at least to me... // => Maybe a "better" Title could be: "Should Ads on Stack Overflow support Accessibility?" :idea:

Comment: @chivracq No, I think the title is fine as it is. Accessibility, or its various declinations, should pretty much ring that bell anyway so if a few people learn that as a side-effect, all the better.

Comment: @Felix, yeah, as you wish but I don't agree, a Thread/Qt Title should be clear and unambiguous and I find "Should X be accessible?" ambiguous and vague as all I think is "accessible [to what...? 70%] or [to whom...? 30%]", +Screenshots in non-English, then I think/thought "hum, OK, non-English native User, they probably mean(t) "visible" or "displayed" and don't want to see those Ads, hum, me neither, => good for a (+1)", ... that I can't retract now... => "Accessibility" could better have been used in the Title, and "accessible" in the Body would be fine...

Comment: The term accessible is used everywhere over [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility), the question has the accessibility tag, it mentions screen readers, and I finish by saying that there's nothing on the ad guidelines that talk about accessibility

Comment: Yeah well, I don't "study" the Content of 'w3.org' everyday, ah-ah...! As part of the "Discussion", Tag also used for this Thread, I just give the Feedback that I didn't connect "accessible" with "Accessibility", you do what you want with that Feedback... // And Win10 that I use as OS doesn't seem to know "accessible" at all either, a Win-Search doesn't retrieve any single relevant Hit on "accessible", while "Accessibility" finds 12 Apps and Setting Sections related to "Ease of Access"...

Comment: @chivracq No need for such hyperboles, nobody's talking about studying the content of w3.org each day. Like, once a year would be enough. "Accessible" being related to accessibility is something that, as a programmer, you must know. And I use "must" purposefully here. No need to study the content every day to know about accessibility. For instance, now you know, it took 5 minutes. If we weren't arguing about it, it would have been even quicker.

Comment: Yeah-yeah, you "win", I don't want to "pollute" this Thread with a badly formulated Title anymore... `Alt="We are just \"acting\" like Trolls, ah-ah...!"` :wink: